# Perplexing assignment behavior with h5py object as instance variable

Tags: python, h5py

I'm using h5py to access HDF5 files and store the h5py File objects in a class. But I'm experiencing some strange behavior in attempting to reassign a closed h5py file instance variable with a new one:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.h5file = None
        self.filename = filename

    def vartest(self):
        self.h5file = h5py.File(self.filename, 'r')
        print self.h5file
        self.h5file.close()
        print self.h5file
        newh5file = h5py.File(self.filename, 'r')
        print newh5file
        self.h5file = newh5file
        print self.h5file
        print newh5file

def main():
    filename = sys.argv[1]
    mycls = MyClass(filename)
    mycls.vartest()
```

Output:

```
<HDF5 file "test.h5" (mode r, 92.7M)>
<Closed HDF5 file>
<HDF5 file "test.h5" (mode r, 92.7M)>
<Closed HDF5 file>
<Closed HDF5 file>
```

Attempting to update the instance variable with the newly opened h5py File object appears to have somehow affected the state of the object, closing it. Regardless of the implementation on the h5py side, I don't see how this behavior makes sense from my understanding of the Python language (i.e., no overloading of the assignment operator).

This example is run with Python 2.6.5 and h5py 1.3.0. If you want to try this example but don't have an HDF5 file sitting around you can just change the file access mode from 'r' to 'a'.

Comment: Does it print "closed" if you comment out `self.h5file = newh5file` line? Is `self.h5file` a [property](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property)? Does `h5py.File()` hold some global state?

Comment: If I comment out `self.h5file = newh5file` then interestingly both `newh5file` and `self.h5file` (which I explicitly closed) show up as being open `<HDF5 file "test.h5" (mode r, 800 bytes)>`. The example is self-contained, self.h5file is not a property. I can't tell you much about the implementation of `h5py.File()`, I wouldn't be surprised if there is some global state, but I don't understand how simply assigning an instance variable changes that global state (someone is doing reference counting somewhere?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a known bug in h5py 1.3, which shows up when you use HDF5 1.8.5 or newer.  It's related to changes in the way identifiers are handled in 1.8.5.  You can fix it by using HDF5 1.8.4 or earlier, or by upgrading to h5py 2.0.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that out, it would be helpful if you happen to have a reference to a mailing list post or bug report that discusses this.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help, but searching through the source code I found this (abbreviated):

```
class HLObject(object):
    def __nonzero__(self):
        register_thread()
        return self.id.__nonzero__()

class Group(HLObject, _DictCompat):
    ...

class File(Group):
    def __repr__(self):
        register_thread()
        if not self:
            return "<Closed HDF5 file>"
        return '<HDF5 file "%s" (mode %s, %s)>' % \
            (os.path.basename(self.filename), self.mode,
             _extras.sizestring(self.fid.get_filesize()))
```

Because there is no `__str__` method, `__repr__` is called to produce the output, and `__repr__` first calls `register_thread()`, then checks to see if `self` is alive (better known as evaluating to True or False).

Python then searches the classes until it finds `__nonzero__` (which again calls `register_thread()`), then returns `self.id.__nonzero__()`, which is apparently returning False.

So, you are correct in that the issue is not with the name binding (assignment), but why `register_thread` and/or `self.id` is bombing out on you, I do not know.

Comment: That is interesting. I wasn't familiar with __nonzero__, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @David No problem.  In Python 3 `__nonzero__` has been renamed to `__bool__`; also, if this method does not exist, `__len__` is tried (0 = `False`, otherwise `True`); if `__len__` also does not exist, all instances of that class are considered `True`.