# How to use h5py to access multiple HDF5 files stored on Google Team Drives? The data in the different files look identical in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, hdf5, h5py, google-drive-shared-drive

I am trying to use h5py to access (read/write/copy) multiple HDF5 files that are stored on a Google Team Drive. I am using Google File Stream, and my Google Team Drive appears in Explorer as a mounted drive (G:). Additionally, I have selected the option to make my files available offline.

I am able to read and write individual HDF5 files to and from my Google Team Drive if I only have one file open at a time in h5py. However, if I have multiple files open simultaneously in h5py, then the internal structure (groups, datasets, and data) in each HDF5 file (as read by h5py) looks identical to the first file I opened.

Here is an example to demonstrate my problem. First, let's create two simple HDF5 files on the Google Team Drive:

```
from pathlib import Path
import h5py

# Set up path and filenames
folder = Path(r'G:\Team Drives\Shared Drive')
filename1 = folder / 'file1.h5'
filename2 = folder / 'file2.h5'

# Create first HDF5 file
h5file1 = h5py.File(filename1, 'a')
h5file1.create_dataset('data1', data=1)
h5file1.close()

# Create second HDF5 file
h5file2 = h5py.File(filename2, 'a')
h5file2.create_dataset('data2', data=2)
h5file2.close()
```

Next, let's open the HDF5 files one at a time and print the names of the datasets in each file:

```
h5file1 = h5py.File(filename1, 'r')
print(f'{h5file1}: datasets = {list(h5file1.keys())}')
h5file1.close()
h5file2 = h5py.File(filename2, 'r')
print(f'{h5file2}: datasets = {list(h5file2.keys())}')
h5file2.close()
```

The result is:

```
<HDF5 file "file1.h5" (mode r)>: datasets = ['data1']
<HDF5 file "file2.h5" (mode r)>: datasets = ['data2']
```

which is exactly what I would expect. Now, let's open both HDF5 files at the same time and again print the names of the datasets in each file:

```
h5file1 = h5py.File(filename1, 'r')
h5file2 = h5py.File(filename2, 'r')
print(f'{h5file1}: datasets = {list(h5file1.keys())}')
print(f'{h5file2}: datasets = {list(h5file2.keys())}')
h5file1.close()
h5file2.close()
```

Now, the result is:

```
<HDF5 file "file1.h5" (mode r)>: datasets = ['data1']
<HDF5 file "file2.h5" (mode r)>: datasets = ['data1']
```

Even though the file handles indicate that they are pointing to different file names, h5py reads the internal data structure (groups, datasets, and data) of both files as identical to the first file that was opened.

Although I can open one file at a time if I am reading files, this becomes a problem if I want to copy a dataset from an existing file to a new file. For example, let's try to copy the dataset 'data1' from file1 to a new file:

```
filename3 = folder / 'file3.h5'
h5file3 = h5py.File(filename3, 'a')
h5file1 = h5py.File(filename1, 'r')
h5file1.copy('data1', h5file3)
```

This produces the following error:

```
KeyError: "Unable to open object (object 'data1' doesn't exist)"
```

because file1 was opened after file3, and file3 does not contain the dataset 'data1'. If I instead open file1 before file3, then I get:

```
OSError: Unable to create file (file exists)
```

The only workaround I have been able to use so far is to first create file3 on my local (C:) drive, copy the dataset from file1 to file3, close both files, and then move file3 to the Google Team Drive.

I found these forum posts ([Python HDF5 H5Py issues opening multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7675838/python-hdf5-h5py-issues-opening-multiple-files) and [Perplexing assignment behavior with h5py object as instance variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355545/perplexing-assignment-behavior-with-h5py-object-as-instance-variable)) which discussed a similar problem when the same Python variable name was reassigned to a different h5py file instance variable. However, I think that my problem is different because I am using unique variable names, and the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7368070) to one of the questions stated that the problem could be fixed by using h5py 2.0 or higher (I am using h5py 2.9.0).

I also read the blog post [HDF in the Cloud](http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2018/02/06/hdf-in-the-cloud), which states that there are issues accessing HDF5 files on the cloud unless you can convince your operating system that the cloud is a normal file system. However, I thought that using Google File Stream would do that, since it is mounted as my G: drive.

Am I misunderstanding something about h5py or about how my Google Team Drive is mounted? Is there some way for me to be able to use h5py to access multiple HDF5 files on Google Team Drive?

Note: I am running Python 3.7 and h5py 2.9.0 on a 64-bit Windows 10 machine.